# TLS session resumption MicroPython

Tags: python, ssl, micropython

Does anybody know if there is a possibility to use TLS session resumption in MicroPython?

Till now I realized a TLS Server in Python with Cert which communicates with my STM32F7DISCO. So fine so good. But because of the lack of power, the STM needs ca. 6 to 7 seconds to finish the TLSv1.2 Server/Client Handshake.

[image: Wireshark screenshot showing part of TLS handshake]

So I attempted to reuse the session, to reduce the handshake time spent by the STM for the next message. But I only get the error:

```
('192.168.178.82', '255.255.255.0', '192.168.178.1', '192.168.178.1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 58, in <module>
  File "main.py", line 27, in open
AttributeError: 'SSLSocket' object has no attribute 'session'
```

which makes it quite clear, why I can't reuse the session. That's because there is no session implemented in the ussl module.

Here's my client Code so far:

```py
import usocket as socket
import ussl as ssl
import random
# import time

__version__ = '0.2.0'
__subversion__ = 'Client'
__author__ = "Philipp"

class send_data:
    def __init__(self):
        # Daten für die Verbindung und den Zähler
        self.server_port = 2002
        self.server_ip = '192.168.178.67'
        self.server_address = (self.server_ip, self.server_port)
        self.server_ca = 'cert/server-cert.der'
        self.session_nr = None
        self.server_ca_bytes = None
    
    def open(self):
        # Verbindung zum Server herstellen
        with open(self.server_ca, 'rb') as f:
            self.server_ca_bytes = f.read()
            
        client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        client_socket.connect(self.server_address)
        ssl_context = ssl.wrap_socket(client_socket, cadata=self.server_ca_bytes)
        self.session_nr = ssl_context.session
        ssl_context.close()
        client_socket.close()
    
    def send(self, msg_nr: int) -> Iterator[int]:
    
        with open(self.server_ca, 'rb') as f:
            self.server_ca_bytes = f.read()

        try:
            # Daten zum Server senden
            client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            client_socket.connect(self.server_address)
            ssl_context = ssl.wrap_socket(client_socket, cadata=self.server_ca_bytes, session=self.session_nr)
    
            msg = "MSG from Client " + str(msg_nr)
            ssl_context.write(msg.encode('utf-8'))
    
            ssl_context.close()
            client_socket.close()
    
            return 0
        except Exception as e:
            return 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    msg_nr = 0
    error_count = 0
    tls_com = send_data()
    
    tls_com.open()
    
    while True:
        return_msg = tls_com.send(msg_nr)
        error_count += return_msg
        print('Versendet Nr: ', msg_nr)
        print('Fehler: ', error_count)
        msg_nr += 1

        # wait_timer = random.randint(1,9)
        # wait_timer = 1
        # print('Wartezeit: ', wait_timer)
        # time.sleep(wait_timer)
```

Comment: Which version of micropython are you using?

Comment: My bad. It`s the 1.20

Comment: Till now I just found the implementation of "pycom. These guys documented it at their page, but it looks like they are in a insolvency proceeding (if this is the correct term). [LINK](https://docs.pycom.io/firmwareapi/micropython/ussl/).